# Block for users asking several heavily down-voted questions in a row

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

The user [robortpeter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/24468/robortpeter) managed to spam our community with four questions within twenty minutes. Each question was heavily down-voted.

To block spam like this, my feature request is to block any user who asks several questions in a row where each one gets heavily down-voted. As an example algorithm: If a user asked two questions within the last hour with a total vote count of less than -6 points, then apply a block for five hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "question banning", and [already exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294). The exact criteria for when somebody gets banned isn't public, but when they try to post they'll get the error:

> - Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

You can read all about it at that link; it goes to an FAQ post on the main meta

Comment: Is it on for U&L?

Comment: @YannisRizos I thought it was on everywhere, but apparently not. We can get it turned on if we start to have a spam problem

Comment: It's a per site feature, and it's off by default.

Comment: "users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do" - sounds very interesting. Is there any site where this is turned on?

Comment: @Nils At least SO and Programmers; I'm not sure about the others. If you check MSO you can find [people asking about it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=c1kwu) (although a ton of those posts get deleted since they're all duplicates)

Comment: Nevertheless I think it is a bit extreme. Especially the IP-bound-part. Who does not use NAT at bigger companies or whose provider does not use DHCP with a limited number of IPs? Is there nothing softer, like "if banning were active - your question/answer would be banned"?